# Установка ItemsSource для ContexMenu

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно задавать меню коллекцией объектов.

```
public class Color
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public ObservableCollection<Color> Colors = new ObservableCollection<Color>()
{
    new Color {Name = "black"},
    new Color {Name = "white"},
    new Color {Name = "red"},
};
```

Но не могу разобраться как правильно биндить коллекцию. Делаю так, но безрезультатно. Понимаю, что проблема из-за того, что `DataContext` не забирается у `mainWindow`, но как сделать правильно?

```
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=DataContext}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}" />
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: А как вы к `mainWindow` байдинг делаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ContextMenu не являеться частью визуального дерева поэтому он не может найти mainWindow. Данные необходимо брать из ContextMenu.PlacementTarget.

```
 <Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu
        DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}" />
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

Кстати у вас Colors не свойсто, а поле.